# UIBarButton not showing in UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I need help with my `UIBarButtonItem` not showing in my `UINavigationBar`.

I am trying to put a `UINavigationBar` in my **third view**. As I am not quite sure if `UINavigationController` will work, I decided to manually initialized a `UINavigationBar`, together with its `UINavigationItem` `initwithTitle`. The code works, but my problem is adding a `UIBarButtonItem` because it won't show in the `UINavigationBar`.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];

    UINavigationItem *navigationItem = [[UINavigationItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Title"];
    [navigationBar pushNavigationItem:navigationItem animated:NO];

    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(showPI:)];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = button;

    UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 44.0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height - navigationBar.frame.size.height) style:UITableViewStylePlain];
    self.tableView = tableView;

    [self.view addSubview:tableView];
    [self.view addSubview:navigationBar];
    [self showCurrencies];

    self.tableView.dataSource = self;
    self.tableView.delegate = self;
}
```

I'm not sure what's missing.

Comment: Why do you think your nag controller won't work?

Comment: I managed to alter my code earlier using `UINavigationController` and crashed. So I redo it and continue using the approach shown above.

Comment: Could you post some details for your nag controller and crash? Thanks.

Comment: By the way, just for clarifications. You will initialize `UINavigationController` in `application: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` of **AppDelegate**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, you're creating your own navigationBar. Try not to alloc init your navigationItem, instead use

```
UINavigationBar *navigationBar = [[UINavigationBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 320.0, 44.0)];
UINavigationItem *item = [navigationBar.items lastObject];
```

Then set your created barbuttonItem to the item's rightBarButtonItem,

```
item.rightBarButtonItem = button;
```

It's works for me.